# Highcharts legend div not rendered and replaced by tspan

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to update a legend using a callback because I am using highchartserver with an api and this is the only way to have a custom legend calling this service.

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/39abdc1w/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
    
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    
    }, function(chart) { // on complete
     
        
    chart.legend.update({enabled:true,useHtml:true,symbolRadius:0,symbolHeight:0,symbolWidth:0, squareSymbol:false});

    chart.series[0].update({name:
    '<div style="display:flex;align-items:center"><div style="margin-right:5px;width:10px;height:10px;border-radius:5px;background-color:#00ffff;"></div><span style="margin-right:10px">'+chart.series[0].name+' - 90%</span><div style="margin-right:5px;width:10px;height:10px;border-radius:5px;background-color:#00ffff;"></div><span style="margin-right:10px">'+chart.series[0].name+' - 70%</span><div style="margin-right:5px;width:10px;height:10px;border-radius:5px;background-color:#ff00f5;"></div><span style="margin-right:10px">'+chart.series[0].name+' - 50%</span></div>'
    }); 
    
})});
```

I don't understand why my divs are replaced by tspan how can I avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Highcharts docs we can read:

> **HTML in Highcharts**
>
> Texts and labels in Highcharts are given in HTML, but as the HTML is
> parsed and rendered in SVG, only a subset is supported. The following
> tags are supported: `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<em>`, `<br/>`, `<span>`. Spans can
> be styled with a style attribute, but only text-related CSS that is
> shared with SVG is handled.
>
> Most places where text is handled in Highcharts, it is also followed
> by an option called useHTML. When this is true, the text is laid out
> as HTML on top of the chart. This allows for full HTML support and can
> be a good idea if you want to add images in your labels, tables in
> your tooltip etc. (...)

So, you need to enable `useHTML` for `legend`:

```
legend: {
  useHTML: true
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ad975ru3/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.useHTML

Comment: Yes I know that, I just set useHtml:true instead of useHTML:true ..